# Laravel blade - How to add "selected" to option form menu on a dynamic modal

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm sending data to my modal using data- attributes on my modal button.

In my "edit" modal I have a form that has a select menu where I need to return if an option is already selected.

I can do this normally using blade like this...

```
@foreach($companyUsers as $manager)
   <option id="manager-option" value="{{ $manager->id }}" {{ $manager->id == $user->manager_id ? 'selected' : '' }}> {{ $manager->userFormatted() }}</option>
@endforeach
```

But I need to insert the $user->manager_id dynamically via js.
So here is my js

```
$('#editUser').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var user = button.data('user')
  var userManager = button.data('user-manager')

  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.k-form').attr('action', '/usermanagement/' + user)
  modal.find('#manager-option').attr('selected', userManager) // here i'm stuck
})
```

So where I have `modal.find('.manager-option').attr(userManager)` I need to somehow replace `$user->manager_id` in my blade file with the variable from my js `userManager`

Comment: You're using `$('.manager-option')`, but I don't see `class="manager-option"` anywhere in your code. Also sidenote, you're setting `id="manager-option"` on an element in a loop. `ids` are unique; you can't do this. If you try to use `$('#manager-option')`, it won't select what you're expecting.

Comment: Oh mistake with the class should be #manager-option there. Right I get that it will need to be unique but that's not the problem i'm trying to solve.

Comment: Except it is somewhat related. If you leave `id="manager-option`, all `<option>` elements will have the same ID, and you're using `modal.find('#manager-option')`, which will always target the last `<option>`. Also, `.attr('selected')` expects a `true/false` as the 2nd param, not a string that `userManager` is.

Comment: Yes it is related and I understand and can fix that. My main questing is how do I use the userManager variable instead of $user->manager_id in my blade file? I need a different way to do this {{ $manager->id == $user->manager_id ? 'selected' : '' }}

Comment: Gotcha. You'd have to query for it: `modal.find('.manager-option[value=' + userManager + ']').attr('selected', true)` (or similar, like setting the `<select>`'s value to `userManager`, etc.)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. Ran a test with a unique id on `<option id="manager-option-2" value="1570" >test</option>`  updated js `modal.find('#manager-option-2[value=' + userManager + ']').attr('selected', true)` but does not insert the selected attr

Comment: Oh well if you're making the ids dynamic, like `manager-option-{id}`, then you can just do `modal.find('#manager-option-' + userManager).attr('selected', true)`. If you `console.log(userManager)`, does it return `2`?

Comment: This is working. Testing successfully now. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! If you've got a second, feel free to add your working code as an answer below, and accept it (when you are allowed) to proper close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to fix this with @Tim Lewis suggestions.

Blade:

```
@foreach($companyUsers as $manager)
    <option class="manager-option-{{ $manager->id }}" value="{{ $manager->id }}"> {{ $manager->userFormatted() }}</option>
@endforeach
```

JS:

```
$('#editUser').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var user = button.data('user')
    var userName = button.data('user-name')
    var userManager = button.data('user-manager')

    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.k-form').attr('action', '/usermanagement/' + user)
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('Edit: ' + userName)
    modal.find('.manager-option-' + userManager).attr('selected', true)
})
```